# Not all domains interpreted as link on Android when QR code scanned

Tags: android, url, qr-code

I don't know if this is normal behavior or not, but if I put a URL with the common extensions like (.com, .net, .org, etc.) into a QR code and scan it, it directly goes to the browser.
If I put a URL with the not-so-common extensions like (.link, .company, etc.) it opens it as a text.

My understanding is that if there is a protocol http or https it should open a browser. Am I correct?

Both links have https:// protocol in front

Example: https://example.com

[image]

Example: https://example.link

[image]

Just scan both codes to see the difference.

Is there anything I can do with the link that I am sending in order to trigger the browser for .link for example?

**Here is what I am getting**

[image]

Comment: It is opening the browser for me, but link is broken.

Comment: yes, it is a sample link. it should open anything. Just uploaded my result

Comment: Are you using your own QR scanning app?  Because I tried with multiple scanning app and it's redirecting me to a browser.

Comment: its the scanner app I got with the phone (Redmi Note 7).

Comment: Can you try with a different app?

Comment: @Kunu, you are right. with another APP is working. Wondering why it doesn't with the build-in app.